# Failed to install ClosedXML dependency

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, closedxml

I need to install ClosedXML dependency to build a C# project with .net framework 4.7.2 but when trying to install I always get the same error: "Cannot resolve dependency 'SixLabors.Fonts'. Sources used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'"

I have tried everything to install from the nuget package manager

Comment: Can you please check for package source url : https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: This is my URL: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: Yes, go to the package manager console and put the following command before installing ClosedXML: NuGet\Install-Package SixLabors.Fonts -Version 1.0.0-beta19

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What version are you trying to install? I think you should install SixLabors.Fonts first and then install ClosedXML, as the newer versions of ClosedXML depend on it.

Comment: I am using version 0.97.0. Can I install SixLabors.Fonts from nuget packages?

Comment: Yes, In the Manage NuGet Packages UI, check the Include prerelease and it would appear or install it from the console - https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.Fonts

Answer (score 30):

I faced the same proplem when trying to install [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML) today. `ClosedXML` depends on the [SixLabors.Fonts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.Fonts/) library which is only available in **beta** at the moment.

To find the library with the NuGet Browser, make sure to check the "Include prerelease" box. You should then be able to find it listed below. After installing `SixLabors.Fonts`, you should be able to install `ClosedXml` without any further issues.

[image]

Comment: "make sure to check the "Include prerelease" box" did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: NPOI has this same issue and it's resolved the same way